# Reformatting a C++ class into other files

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have been working on a rather basic logging class in c++. I now need to move the class outside of my main file but I don't know what to put into the header file. most of my confusion lies in the enumeration of my logging levels.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Log {
public:
    enum Level {
        LevelError, LevelWarning, LevelInfo
    };
private:
    Level LogLevel = LevelInfo;
public:
    void set_level(Level level) {
        LogLevel = level;
    }
    void Error(const char* message) {
        if (LogLevel >= LevelError) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR]: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void Warn(const char* message) {
        if (LogLevel >= LevelWarning) {
            std::cout << "[WARNING]: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void Info(const char* message) {
        if (LogLevel >= LevelInfo) {
            std::cout << "[INFO]: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

PS feedback on how I can improve this terrible class is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Think through why you would allow a user to sent an error message to an info logger in the first place and whether or not it's a good idea to just silently discard the message if they get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That actually seems just fine as you have it. You could put the whole thing as-is into a `Log.h` file, or split it into `Log.h/Log.cpp`, where the .h contains the class definition and the .cpp file contains the four class methods.